# Distribution of access token expiry reasons - favors removal of user as Page admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token

We're seeing some strange behavior in the reasons why access tokens are expiring for Pages using our app. We're using the offline_access permission, and aren't experiencing any problems in data collection (limits, errors, etc.).

Several of the users whose Page tokens expired are actual owners of the Page. If a token expires, it's odd that we get a reason for expiry as 'removed from admin role'.

After speaking with some of the users who appear to have been removed as admins, I found that no one explicitly removed them from the admin role - FB seems to have done so of its own accord.
Is this a documented behavior?

Some numbers:

- 76 : Total access tokens expired (out of several hundred authorized tokens)
- 22 (28.9%) : Changed account password *(Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.)*
- 52 (68.42%) : Removed as admin of Page *(The user must be an administrator of the page in order to impersonate it.)*
- 2 (2.6%) : Revoked access to the app *(Error validating access token: User has not authorized application.)*

The numbers appear to be heavily skewed. Is this kind of distribution common?
How common is it for users to be removed as admins from Pages?
Anyone have insight into user behavior - do they remove admin access instead of revoking app access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is currently in the process of deprecating the offline_access permission.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/ and  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/ for some ways to handle expired tokens.

As far as the inner workings of Facebook, your guess is as good as mine as to what they're doing with page administrators.  This is definitely of concern to me as one of my production apps deals with pages and offline_access.  As of yet, I have not seen an issue with admins being revoked page administration rights.  I will keep my eye out for it.

Check your app settings to see what `deprecate offline_access:` is set to for your app(s) at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appid}/advanced`

Comment: Thanks. This has been an issue since before FB announced that particular deprecation - we're currently still using offline_access.

We've gone over both links you've mentioned before, but haven't found any explanation or hint of this behavior.